# Destructuring props in function component from mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

Container `ListRegisteredProducts` passes props to the purely functional component `TableView` with:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        products: state.products
    }
}
```

And the connect function looks like this:

```
const ListRegisteredProducts = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(TableView)
```

But when I go to destructure the props:

```
const TableView = ({products}) => (

...

TableView.propTypes = {
    products: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
            id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
        })
    )
}
```

I am getting an error thrown saying that products is not an array, but an object.

**Edit:** when I log the `products` that I have destructured in the arguments of TableView, I see the entire state of my app:

```
{isFetching: false, products: Array(0)}
```

Comment: Try doing a console to see what the `product` is showing.

Comment: shows `{isFetching: false, products: Array(0)}` AKA the entire state of redux at this point in the app

Comment: when you just console `products` in `TableView` component what does it show?

Comment: what I said above is what it shows

Comment: You need to extract an array `products: state.products ? state.products.products : []` right now products is object that contains array as one of its properties.

Answer (score 0):

As per definition of `products`,its an array of object.

From this defination React do **typechecking**.

```
products: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
            id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
        })
    );
```

But its look like you are passing `products` from `mapStateToProps` is typeof object.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user: { lang_default: lang, authorized}) => ({
    lang,
    authorized
});
```